# JQuery UI 1.12.1 Autocomplete Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have some issues in getting JQuery UI to work.

The version of query UI which I am using is the latest 1.12.1. I downloaded the autocomplete (and all the other required widgets).

In my project I have include jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui-min.js and jquery.js into the "Scripts" folder. I have also included "images" folder, jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui-min.css into "Content" folder.

**Layout view**

```
...
<head>
    ...
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Home view**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbxTest").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("SearchElement", "Home")'
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("searchText", null, new { id = "tbxTest" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
...
public JsonResult SearchElement(string term)
{
    List<string> testingElement = new List<string>() { "Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta" };

    List<string> searchResult = testingElement.Where(x => (string.Compare(x, term, true) == 0)).ToList();

    return Json(searchResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I tried placing breakpoint on the first line in the controller method but it didn't got triggered. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Order matters, put jquery.js first and then ui stuff. See if that works. Otherwise, check the console and let us know if you see any errors there.

Comment: You are right. order matters. After reordering and correct some minor mistake, I manage to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your jquery

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It works for me.